# Socket.io and Passport - Get passport userID on socket connection?

Tags: node.js, sockets

Essentially I want to get the UserID of a user that connects to socket.io.

If the user isn't signed in, I'll ignore the socket connection request - otherwise I'd store the Passport UserID and the socket connection ID in redis.

My question, then: How do I get Passport user from the socket object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the existing libraries that solve this problem don't work with the current version of Socket.io, I've decided to go with the following:

I'm using MongoStore as my session store:

```
var sid = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie)['connect.sid'];
    sessionStore.get(sid.split('.')[0].split(':')[1], function (err, session) {
        if (session.passport.user) {
            console.log('io found user logged in');
        } else {
            console.log('io found no user');
        }
    })
```

If I find that a user is logged in, I'll store their userID and socket.io connection information in Redis. When I need to push a notification to a user, I'll query redis for their userID and emit on the socket ID I find. When a user disconnects, I remove the entry for their user ID.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/) good explanation of how to realize authentication with Socket.IO, have you read that?

Comment: broken link, this page doesn't exist anymore